# nextjs: Multiple children were passed to <Link> with `href` of 'x' but only one child is supported

Tags: next.js

I'm not passing multiple children to the Link, why am I getting this error? The error is:
"Multiple children were passed to  with `href` of `/post/61703ea640ff7eef1e1e7e75` but only one child is supported"

```
return (
        <>
        {head()}
        <div className="container-fluid"
        style={{
            backgroundImage: "url( "+ "/images/default.jpg"+ ")",
            backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
            padding: "100px 0px 75px 0px",
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundPosition: 'center center',
            display: 'block'
        }}>
                <h1 className="display-1 font-weight-bold text-center py-5">MERNCAMP</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
        <div className="row pt-5">
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <div key={post._id} className="col-md-4">
              <Link href={`/post/view/${post._id}`}>
                <a>
                  <PostPublic key={post._id} post={post} />
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
          </>    
    )
```

Comment: Are you using `Link` elsewhere? The error references `/post/61703ea640ff7eef1e1e7e75` but the links you're rendering in the code have `/post/view/${post._id}` as the `href` value. These are probably not the cause of the error.

Answer (score 8):

Wrap the entire link with one div

```js
<Link key={post._id} href={`/post/${post.slug.current}`}>
            <div>
              <div>
                <img src={urlFor(post.mainImage).url()} alt=''></img>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>{post.title}</p>
                <p>
                  {post.description} by {post.author.n`enter code here`ame}
                </p>
              </div>
              <img src={urlFor(post.author.image).url()!} alt=''></img>
            </div>
 </Link>
```

Answer (score 3):

If it helps any one i was getting same error in following e.g code

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <Link href="/something">Link to some page</Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I fixed it by enclosing the text inside a p tag, seems like every block of text/word is considered as new unique "children"

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <Link href="/something">
      <p>Link to some page</p>
    </Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! An empty tag (`<></>`) also does the job

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Are you sure that's how it's written in your source file? This error usually happens if you have a space in between the `<Link>` and the `<a>` tags.

Example:

```js
...
{posts.map((post) => (
  <div key={post._id} className="col-md-4">
    <Link href={`/post/view/${post._id}`}> <a>
      <PostPublic key={post._id} post={post} />
    </a></Link>
  </div>
))}
```

You see the space in between the tags in `` <Link href={`/post/view/${post._id}`}> <a> ``

Comment: yeah, I checked that before posting it actually. still having the error. weird.

Comment: Weird indeed... Can you provide more specific instructions to reproduce your problem? Like a self contained Nextjs Page.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is too late but just in case...

I got the same error and I solved by just restarting the development server, I know that is so silly but worked for me.

Also, be sure that your component `<PostPublic />` doesn't have `Link` inside, my theory is probably is nesting links to your main Link child that is been mapped. Hope can help that to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a path such as /xxx/[id]/[[...slug]].js make sure you don't forget the slug or that it is not null in your href. This is the error you will get if missing.